# Get the position(index) of an element in the parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the position of a an element in its parent. For example

```
<div>
<h2 class="one">A</h2>
<span>Something</span>
<h2 class="two">B</h2>
<h2 class="three">C</h2>
</div>
```

Now suppose I get a reference of h2.two $('h2.two'); in an event. I want the position of this element relative to other h2's in the div. In this case it is 2. and please don't tell me I can get it through the classname, because there won't be these classnames. Its just for explanation.

NB: I want its position in the list of h2, basically in $('h2.two').parent().children('h2') not all elements

```
function buildPath(element)
{
var Xpath,position=-1;
element=$(element);//Just in case;
Xpath=getTagName(element);
parent=element.parent();
console.log(parent.children(Xpath));

var position = element.siblings(Xpath).element.index(element);//I want the position here
Xpath="/"+Xpath+"["+position+"]";
    console.log(Xpath);
    console.log(getTagName(parent));
    if (getTagName(element)=='body')
    return Xpath;



 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var $theH2 =  $('h2.two');

var index = $theH2.siblings("h2").andSelf().index($theH2);
```

Here is a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Bm6Wd/

Click on an h2 and it will alert the index.

Comment: Actually @James' solution works well using jQuery 1.4.4 and beyond: http://jsfiddle.net/9D9wK/ Somesh: Which version of jQuery are you using?